# Is Fullmetal Alchemist considered as a magical realist type story?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series, fullmetal-alchemist-manga

I have a project due where I have to compare and contrast two magical realist stories. I thought that it would be better to include a manga because they are very different from normal books, and I chose *Fullmetal Alchemist*.

A magical realist story is a story where society is much like real life, or similar to somewhere in real life. In this society, a certain magical element is commonplace. In this case, the science "Alchemy" is commonplace in a realistic Military Dictatorship type rule.

Is *Fullmetal Alchemist* considered as such?

Comment: I don't think you could consider FMA to be Magical Realism. All though set in a timeperiod similar to the world wars, the worlds technology is significantly more advanced (eg. automails). Steampunk with some magitek would better fit the bill. But genre identification is not really my strong suit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fullmetal Alchemist is a mostly steampunk genre, A retrofuturistic subgenre of science fiction that incorporates technology and aesthetic designs inspired by 19th-century industrial steam-powered machinery.

Not really magical because with magic you mostly get reactions like "What the hell how did that happen?".

While alchemy is more systematical like science.
Although the thing with his brother being a soul in a suit of armor made no sense. Except for things related to souls, everything else is mostly science/technology-based.

Even if you consider alchemy a form of magic it is mostly based on the 19th-century industrial steam-powered era with barely any form of electricity so not really realism either. And there is also the automail prosthetics that are more advanced and almost fantastical.